# I am trying to represent an avatar with data from an Oculus headset, and I cannot find out how to properly represent it

Tags: 3d, virtual-reality, oculus, avatar

**TL;DR**: For a youtube channel, I am going to try and control an avatar in a similar way to the gif below. Essentially recording my movements in VR and then using them in a video.[image]

At my disposal I have an Oculus Rift S and free time to try things out in unity and other programs.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Recording within other games which have built in recording features
   This does not provide me with the customizeability I need
2. Recording within unity
   I have not had success implementing recording at all into unity.

There are clearly a variety of ways to solve this, and I have spent a few hours just trying to get a solution, but I cannot find one which works.

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do, are you trying to go into vr and then have an avatar respond to your voice and movements?

Comment: @vasmos Sorry, I'll edit it. I'm trying to record an avatar that can respond to my voice and movements - and then use a video of it in YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty big project but

Create rigged/animated avatar in Unity ->

Setup Animation state machine ->

Setup logic to switch to different states based on input (different states for hand/mouth animations) ->

Have logic to fire different animation state triggers, perhaps also play an audio clip from an audio source

Optional:

Take microphone input ->

Have AI speech recognition or just sample microphone volume for general sound input ->

Comment: I like this idea, it was what I have been thinking of, but do you know of an easy way to record in unity other than a screencapture?

Comment: no sorry I don't think there is anything built in, I would check package manager/asset store